# Is my understanding of the argument correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-verification

I worked through a proof of:

$$ f(z) = {1\over 2 \pi i}\int_{\partial D} {f(w) \over w -z} dw$$

where $D\subset \mathbb C$ is an open disk and $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ and continuous on $\overline{D}$.

> Please could someone tell me if my understanding of the proof is right?

Here is the proof in my own words:

Let $\omega = {1\over 2 \pi i} {f(w) \over w - z} dw$ . On $D\setminus B(z,\varepsilon) = D-D_\varepsilon$, $ {f(w) \over w - z} $ is holomorphic hence we may apply Stokes theorem:

$$ 0 = \int_{D-D_\varepsilon} d \omega = \int_{\partial (D - D_\varepsilon)} \omega$$

That is:

$$ \int_{\partial D}  {1\over 2 \pi i} {f(w) \over w - z} dw = \int_{\partial D_\varepsilon}  {1\over 2 \pi i} {f(w) \over w - z} dw$$

Parametrising $\partial D_\varepsilon$ by $\gamma(t) = z + \varepsilon e^{it}$ we get

$$ \int_{\partial D_\varepsilon}  {1\over 2 \pi i} {f(w) \over w - z} dw = {1\over 2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(z + \varepsilon e^{it}) dt$$

The limit of this as $\varepsilon \to 0$ is $f(z)$ hence the claim is reached.